# Как установить другой пакет ПО после установки Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, ос, kali-linux

Ребят, подскажите кое-что. Ставлю Kali Linux на свой ноут, не могу поставить другой пакет программного обеспечения. Скрин показать не могу, но объяснить на словах - окей. При установке есть такой пункт "Выбор и установка программного обеспечения", хочу поставить Kali Linux с GNOME и желательно с large пакетом ПО, но выдаёт ошибку установки. Прикол в том, что если я буду ставить даже default пакет всё равно ошибка. Ставится только top10, который настолько мелкий, что мне не просто не хватит его функционала. Можно как-то после установки Kali Linux поставить все проги из пакета large сразу, а не каждую программу вводить в терминале?

Answer (score 1):

`kali-linux-arm` - Kali Linux ARM system

`kali-linux-core` - Kali Linux base system

`kali-linux-default` - Kali Linux default system

`kali-linux-everything` - Everything in Kali Linux

`kali-linux-headless` - Kali Linux default headless system

`kali-linux-large` - Kali Linux large system

`kali-linux-nethunter` - Kali Linux NetHunter tools

Ответ на вопрос был найден здесь: https://www.kali.org/news/kali-linux-metapackages/